# Determining likely relationship based upon autosomal DNA shared cM

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

Given two tests that share some cM of autosomal DNA, how can I easily find the predicted relationships that such shared cM would suggest?

For example, a 2,200 cM match suggests it could be either: grandparent, half-sibling, or grandchild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Shared cM Project 4.0 tool v4](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4) from DNA Painter project mentioned in [this blog post](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/2017/10/07/using-shared-matches-a-quick-example/) makes it simple.

To jump straight to the relationships a 2,200 cM match may suggest just append the number at the end of that URL: https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/2200

It computes using the information in this chart from the [August 2017 updated to the Shared cM project](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/2017/08/26/august-2017-update-to-the-shared-cm-project/):

[image]