# Using AncestryDNA to verify biological father?

Tags: autosomal-dna

I believe I have finally found my biological father.  I was recently contacted by a possible cousin.

Amount of Shared DNA in Ancestry is 548 centimorgans shared across 31 DNA segments.

In GEDMATCH the Largest segment = 75.3 cM
Total of segments > 7 cM = 625.0 cM
25 matching segments

Estimated number of generations to MRCA = 2.3

Is this a good chance that I have found my long lost family?

Comment: Tanya, if you look at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13459/how-can-i-determine-the-likely-relationship-based-upon-autosomal-dna-shared-cm, you'll find a good tool for assessing the closeness of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like yours are now easily answered using a tool linked to at [How can I determine the likely relationship based upon autosomal DNA shared cM?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13459/how-can-i-determine-the-likely-relationship-based-upon-autosomal-dna-shared-cm)

That DNA Painter tool shows that for [625 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcm/625) a first cousin relationship is possible, and at [548 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcm/548) you are close too.

Click the preceding links to see nice pictures illustrating your possible relationships.